# Divide a std::string without copying

Tags: c++, string

Is it possible to divide a `std::string` into two or more substrings without copying, much like we can use a move constructor to create a new `std::string` without copying?

Comment: You can move only the whole string. That is it is objects that are moved,

Comment: If you absolutely need to avoid copies, can't you just use iterators / indices and length pairs to remember where your sub strings are?

Or you could make copying an std::basic_string object cheaper by using a stack allocator.

Comment: @antred I have already written functions that accept `std::string`s as parameters. It's not the end of the world to rewrite those functions them but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not do this with `std::string`. But, you can do this with `std::string_view` from C++17.

Example:

```
std::string str = "TheBigStr";
std::string_view p1 = std::string_view(str.data() + 3, 3);
```

String view is not copying the data, so `str` should not be modified while the view is used.

Comment: That's a shame, since I don't have access to a C++17 compiler. I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer in case someone comes up with a way to do it in C++14.

Comment: @AlessandroPower There are a few third-party string_ref / string_view implementations floating around on the internet. I've used one in one of my recent projects.

Comment: You might not need a C++17 compiler. GCC's libstdc++ provides `std::experimental::string_view` for C++14 and later. LLVM's libc++ provides `std::string_view` for C++11 and later.

Comment: To use `std::experimental::string_view` you have to include `experimental/string_view` header file

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which compiler you are using but at least Microsoft's GSL has string_span which is essentially a string_view.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?